# Getting a range of objects after an object and hide/show them accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list group that has seperated groups, meaning there are rows in the list group which seperate/group them by assigning title rows in the list by class. I'm trying to hide only the list inside inside the group, I don't want to hide all the list objects like this code does. Does anyone know how to only hide the groups individually so when you click the title of the group it only hides the list inside that group ***(Without modifying any tags in the HTML code)***. Specifically when referring to the code example below, If someone clicks on 'Title 2', then only the `<li>` which are after that and before 'Title 3' disappear/reappear.  Please see the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li class="title">Title 1</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="title">Title 2</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="title">Title 3</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery / Js:**

```
$("ul li.title").click(function(){
  $("ul li").not(".title").toggle();    
});
```

You can find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QNNgE/

Comment: can you add group to the li's??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:-

`$(this).nextUntil('li.title').toggle();`

So when clicking a title, toggle the visibility of all elements after the clicked title, up until the next one.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNNgE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

ok try this approach:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="title">Title 1</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="title">Title 2</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="title">Title 3</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$("ul li.title").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().toggle();    
});
```

hope this helps.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNNgE/2/)

Comment: This puts them in seperate UL tags, I'm trying to avoid that, unless you can do it in code after the DOM is loaded without the additional UL's

Comment: @ZeeTee is there any reason why it must not use multiple `ul` tags?

Comment: Doesn't matter, billyonecan has it handled.

Comment: @ZeeTee, billyonecan has given you the solution without extra `ul` tags.  would nice to know about the `ul` tags though.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is aweful, but works as requested without modifying the HTML:</strike>

EDIT: Ah, I see I've misunderstood the question.

In any case this does a similar thing (something like an accordian) without modifying the HTML.

```
$("ul li.title").click(function(){
    var title = $(this);
    var inGroup = false;
    title.parent().children().each(function(){
        var li = $(this);
        if (li.hasClass('title')) {
            inGroup = li.get(0) == title.get(0);
        } else {
            if (inGroup) {
                li.show();
            } else {
                li.hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
$("ul li.title").eq(0).click();
```